# How to properly type plugins in Cypress

Tags: typescript, testing, cypress

I am finding the typescript support in Cypress is a bit confusing. I was able to achieve correct typing for my custom commands fairly easily. However, I am struggling to get it working with plugins.

For example, if I have this simple `plugins/index.ts` file.

```js
import { generateEmail } from "./my-temp-mail-file"

const pluginConfig = async (on, config) => {
  on("task", {
    generateEmail: async () => {
      const email = await generateEmail()
      return email
    }
  })
}

export default pluginConfig
```

The `on, config` are always undefined types (ie `Parameter 'on' implicitly has an 'any' type`). Even if I include the [type declaration suggested by Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-plugins) it doesn't help.

When I try to use my custom plugins, the return argument available in the `then` method is always `unknown`.

For example `email` is always unknown`.

```js
cy.task("generateEmail").then(email => {
  ///...do something
})
```

At the moment I am importing my types, and this works but a little annoying.

```js
cy.task("generateEmail").then((email: string) => {
  ///...do something
})
```

Is there a way I can have them automatically there like I can with commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the types for `on, config` by hovering `Cypress.PluginConfig`, but admittedly the annotation should be kicking in.

If `generateEmail()` has a return type, it will be inferred in the task

```
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
export default (on: Cypress.PluginEvents, config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions) => {

  on("task", {
    generateEmail: async () => {
      const email = await generateEmail()   // type shows "const email: string"
      return email
    }
  })

}

function generateEmail(): Promise<string> { 
  return Promise.resolve('z')  
}
```

To type the task return value in the test, add this to plugins

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      task(event: 'generateEmail'): Chainable<string>;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
cy.task('generateEmail').then(email => {   // type shows "(parameter) email: string"  
  ...
})
```